# Paint on top of a UI element WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I am making a project that draw Numbers in multicolored random dots.  If you type in a 1,000,000 the scree will slowly paint with 1M dots that look like the number.  I'm migrating to WPF and wanted known if there is an easy wat to pain on top of a text block as that will save a lot of hit testing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) are designed to do exactly that. They allow you to render controls, drawings, or anything you like on a separate layer that is always on top of other controls.